# is it possible to edit the text in a listview column?

Tags: .net, winforms

Is it possible to edit the text in a listview sub-item column in a report view? In other words integrate a combo box or a textbox to facilitate input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this could be of interest?

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/list/extendedlistviews.aspx

Answer (score 0):

In order to allow this you need to set

```
yourListView.LabelEdit = true;
```

This defaults to `false` so you need to explicitly turn it on to allow users to edit the labels.